# Need to import custom package to my class

Tags: java, import, package

Hi I have a custom class which consists of a custom exception folder and 3 .java files.

My structure is com/raeside/family/

So I want to do the following

```
import com.raeside.family.*;
```

But it is just giving me a red underline and when I try to let netbeans repair it, it doesn't work. Where should I store my com/ folder so that I can import it into my java program? I tried storing it inside of projectname/src/ but it's to no avail.

```
package com.raeside.family;

public class W4Q3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

Is my code, my W4Q3 file is in the family folder. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

If all of your classes are in the same package (e.g. com.raeside.family) then you don't need the import statement at all. Make sure that all of your java files are in the src/com/raeside/family directory and have

```
package com.raeside.family;
```

at the top.

Comment: Okay I moved my .java file into the family folder and at the top I have package com.raeside.family; but it still gives me problems. I will add my code to the op.